# VB call to MsiLocateComponent function in msi.dll

Tags: vb.net, winapi, windows-installer

I am trying to get the installation path of Office programs as [this microsoft kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234788/en) suggests (since Office start menu shortcuts don't point to paths anymore; thank you Microsoft).

Of course, the KB example uses C++ and native libraries, which I tried to replicate in VB.NET with the following code

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("msi.dll")> Public Shared Function MsiLocateComponent(szComponent As String, ByRef lpPathBuf As Char(), ByRef pcchBuf As Integer)
End Function
```

I call this function from the following, which I expect to return a message box with at least the dot (if the rest fails). Instead, I get nothing at all, so I assume that the code runs into some sort of error (which is silent though because I get no exception).

```
Shared Function DealWithWinInstallerPath(ProgramPath As String) As String
    Dim sPath(300) As Char
    Dim sSize As Integer = 300
    Dim state As Integer = MsiLocateComponent("{019C826E-445A-4649-A5B0-0BF08FCC4EEE}", sPath, sSize)
    MsgBox(state & ".")
End Function
```

(Note that the function has an argument that will be used in the future, but its contents are just for testing purposes).

Am I declaring the function incorrectly? Passing the wrong arguments? Is msi.dll not the right name for the library? The [msdn database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't help much either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For managed code,  the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller interop assembly found in Windows Installer XML's ([WiX](http://wix.codeplex.com/releases/view/115492)) Deployment Tools Foundation (DTF) is the way to go.   DTF's ComponentInstallation class has a read only property called Path that encapsulates the call to MsiLocateComponent()

Once installed, you can find the DLL in C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.8\SDK.

You can also read through the source code for pointers on how to P/Invoke MSI API calls.

Comment: `pointers on how to P/Invoke MSI API calls` No pun intended I presume? ... Thank you, it works really well.

Comment: LOL. Not at all... didn't realize the humor of what I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

MsiGetComponentPath is preferred if you read the MSDN docs, and there's an interop example here:

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/msi.MsiGetComponentPath

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I have the info required for for GetComponentPath. Either way, Christopher's managed solution above works fine.

Comment: Phil, FWIW the DTF doco says that ComponentInstallation::Path references MsiGetComponentPath, MsiGetComponentPathEx and MsiLocateComponent.  I haven't read through the code so I'm guessing it uses MsiGetComponentPath when needed.

Comment: Here's the source: http://wix.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/DTF/Libraries/WindowsInstaller/ComponentInstallation.cs  It seems to have the logic to handle the various scenarios.